# Navigation Drawer Submenu

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, navigationbar

I have implemented navigation drawer in my project.Everything is fine and the project is all set.I only have a problem with my drawer.On click of every item i have sub items but i do not want to show it in expandable list view,I want to open another sub drawer containing sub items right next to my main navigation drawer. How should i proceed.Please Help.

Code in Context

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    private String[] mTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initToolbar();

        mTitles=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_titles);
        mDrawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mTitles));

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }


    }
    private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.toolbar_title);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);

        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content

    }


}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="#efeaea"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
             space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
             this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
             languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
             The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
             the container. A solid background is used for contrast
             with the content view. -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can implement custom Expandable adapter

list_item.xml //child view inside group

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:divider="@color/black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize14"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_group.xml //parent view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:dividerPadding="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/navImage"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize20"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Collapser"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize20"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

ExpandableListAdapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    private int[] headerIcons;



    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,int[] headerIcons, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this.headerIcons = headerIcons;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }


        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        ImageView headerImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.navImage);

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        TextView lvlPlusMinus=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Collapser);
        if(getChildrenCount(groupPosition)!=0)
        {

            lvlPlusMinus.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

            lvlPlusMinus.setText("+");

            if(isExpanded)
            {
                lvlPlusMinus.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                lvlPlusMinus.setText("-");

            }
        }
        else
        {
            lvlPlusMinus.setText("");
        }

        headerImage.setImageResource(headerIcons[groupPosition]);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

In your Navigation drawer

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
   // private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView mDrawerListView;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    Map<String, String> params;
    HashMap<String, String> userDetails;
    public Fragment fragment = null;
    String  tag,URL ;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;
    private final Handler mDrawerHandler = new Handler();


    /**
     * AppointmentRequest ♠♠
     */
    ProgressDialog bar ;
    public static  final NavigationDrawerFragment NavUtils = new NavigationDrawerFragment();
    public static NavigationDrawerFragment getInstance() {
        return NavUtils;
    }
    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }


    View contentView;
    SessionManager session;
    TextView doctorName;
    ImageView docImage;

    int[] headerIcons;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        session = new SessionManager(getActivity());

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
        headerIcons = new int[]{
                R.drawable.home,
                R.drawable.profile,
                R.drawable.logout
        };

        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);

    }




    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        contentView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer_with_topheader, container, false);

        mDrawerListView = (ExpandableListView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.expList);
        doctorName = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.docName);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), headerIcons, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        mDrawerListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                        && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                    mDrawerListView.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);
                    mDrawerListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);

                }
                lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
            }
        });

        mDrawerListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, final int groupPosition, long id) {

                final String selected = (String) listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
                mDrawerListView.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);

                mDrawerHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                mDrawerHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, 250);

                if (groupPosition == 0 ||)//close drawer if no child
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                return false;
            }
        });


        /**
         * Expandable list child on click listener
         */
        mDrawerListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, long id) {
                final String selected = (String) listAdapter.getChild(
                        groupPosition, childPosition);
                mDrawerListView.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);
                mDrawerHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                mDrawerHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, 250);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                return true;
            }
        });


        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);


        return contentView;
    }
    /*
        * Preparing the list data
        */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding Child in Parent 
        listDataHeader.add("Home");//0
        listDataHeader.add("Profile");//1
        listDataHeader.add("Sign out");//2


        List<String> Profile = new ArrayList<String>();
        Casefile.add("Child 1");
        Casefile.add("Child 2");


        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), new ArrayList<String>());// Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Profile);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), new ArrayList<String>());//if no child
    }
    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the  content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.dehaze);
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.dehaze,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */

        )
        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });



        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }





    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        /*if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }*/
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }



    /**
     * Diplaying view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */

    private void displayView(final int position) {
        // update the  content by replacing fragments

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    tag = "HomeFragment";
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();


                break;
            case 1:
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    tag = "ProfileFragment";
                    fragment = new ProfileFragment();


                break;
            case 2:
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    tag = "Signout";
                    fragment= null;
                    //Signout
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerListView.setSelection(position);
            mDrawerListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
            transaction.commit();



        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please also help me the with the changes in main activity.

Comment: edited my answer please check and I suggest you to use the new implemention of navigation drawer with menu it is simpler than the above method